# react-native-pie Duplicate key

Tags: react-native

```
ExceptionsManager.js:126 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `3`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
    in ARTGroup (at Group.js:35)
    in Group (at Pie.js:129)
    in RoundDividers (at Pie.js:178)
    in ARTGroup (at Group.js:35)
    in Group (at Pie.js:169)
    in ARTSurfaceView (at Surface.js:37)
    in Surface (at Pie.js:168)
    in Pie (at ModaBuyingPower.tsx:105)
    in RCTView (at ModaBuyingPower.tsx:104)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.js:55)
    in SafeAreaView (at ModaBuyingPower.tsx:98)
    in RCTView (at Paper.tsx:58)
    in Paper (created by Context.Consumer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve duplicate key issue using this

react-native pie node modules :-  RoundDividers

key={Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 7)}

key={Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8)}

https://github.com/nihgwu/react-native-pie/issues/39

[image]